# Connect PHP to Interbase: "undefined function ibase_connect()"

Tags: php, database-connection, interbase

hey all im trying to connect my php application to an interbase database and i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Phase\includes\config.php on line 11
```

the line the causes the error is as follows.

```
if(!ibase_connect($config['DBHost'] .":". $config['DBName'], $config['DBUser'], $config['DBPass'])) {
    echo "Connection Error: ". ibase_errmsg();
```

im really new to the php world, can someone please explain what im supposed to do.

**UPDATE**

Sorry I forgot to mention im using a windows 64bit machine if that helps

I get the following when i do the get_loaded_extensions() function

[0] => Core [1] => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => com_dotnet [4] => ctype [5] => date [6] => ereg [7] => filter [8] => ftp [9] => hash [10] => iconv [11] => json [12] => mcrypt [13] => SPL [14] => odbc [15] => pcre [16] => Reflection [17] => session [18] => standard [19] => mysqlnd [20] => tokenizer [21] => zip [22] => zlib [23] => libxml [24] => dom [25] => PDO [26] => bz2 [27] => SimpleXML [28] => wddx [29] => xml [30] => xmlreader [31] => xmlwriter [32] => apache2handler [33] => Phar [34] => mbstring [35] => exif [36] => gd [37] => gettext [38] => imap [39] => mysql [40] => mysqli [41] => pdo_mysql [42] => PDO_ODBC [43] => pdo_sqlite [44] => soap [45] => sockets [46] => SQLite [47] => sqlite3 [48] => xmlrpc [49] => ming [50] => mhash ) –

Answer (score 2):

Have you [enabled](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php) this extension?

Is it shown in php_info() or [get_loaded_extensions()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) ?

Comment: extension does seem to be enabled i just checked my php.ini file and this is what i had extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext" no ; at the beginning !!

Comment: You have to check the output of php_info or the function I posted to see if an extension has been enabled.

Comment: right, I don't see anything base-ish in there, so it's not loaded. Read the link I posted to you to see how this has to be accomplished. Usually you have to load an extension in the php.ini by putting extension=[name] in there.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you work on a Windows based machine. Have you checked your installation is correct? You can give a look at this address: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php

I suspect some DLLs not present.

Comment: the required gds32.dll is present in the following location C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: From [link](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq191/): _The simplest way of adding Firebird support is adding the interbase module to an existing PHP installation. On Windows it's a matter of simply unpacking the PHP .zip package and extracting the PHP_INTERBASE.DLL extension, or choosing the Interbase package while installing from setup.exe installer. Please note that in the latter case, the installer might also install the old gds32.dll from InterBase 6.0, which you need to delete manually and replace with Firebird's fbclient.dll (just rename it to gds32.dll)._